# My port scanner takes too long to scan for ports. Here is my code, could somebody help me?

Tags: python

Here is my code. Can somebody explain to me how to make my port scanner faster? I made the port scanner by connecting to the ip with the 'connect.ex()' and maybe should I use another command?

```
try:
    for port in range(1,1000):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteHost,port))
        if result == 0:
            print(colored("[+] Port {}: Open".format(port), 'green'))
            sock.close()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an existing port scanner built by someone who already did the work to optimize its implementation?

Comment: The easiest change is just moving the work into threads, but (1) balancing performance against load is an art, not a science, and not really amenable to a canonical answer; and (2) writing a *really* high-performance port scanner requires a bunch of close-to-the-OS tricks that typically require root and are *very* much off-topic here.

Comment: I know a lot of Port scanners but I tried to built one because I am trying to learn more and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a quick look on Github led me to find [portSpider](https://github.com/xdavidhu/portSpider) which bills itself as

> A lightning fast multithreaded network scanner framework with modules.

Reading through it, I noticed that it uses [`socket.connect`](https://github.com/xdavidhu/portSpider/blob/master/modules/manual.py#L45) and not `connect_ex`. It absolutely does multithreading though to increase performance. I would tend toward using an existing solution rather than building one from scratch, unless this is just for tinkering.

To speed up your example in particular, you could do a *simple* optimization using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

```
def scan_port(port):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteHost,port))
        if result == 0:
            print(colored("[+] Port {}: Open".format(port), 'green'))
            sock.close()
    except:
        pass  # you should handle this error

import multiprocessing as mp

p = mp.Pool()  # will parallelize to number of CPUs you have
p.map(scan_port, range(1, 1000))
```